# string.localeCompare() with special characters work differently in different browsers

Tags: javascript

```
"%".localeCompare("?")
```

I'm not sure what should be the expected behavior for this, but the problem is it is different for different browsers. I have only tried IE(11), firefox and chrome.

Result:

Chrome: 1 ("?" comes first)

Firefox: -1 ("%" comes first)

IE 11: -1 ("%" comes first)

What is the expected result of comparing special characters like this? Is there not some specification?

Comment: Well obviously - that's rather what "localeCompare" means... But in my opinion `%` should come before `?` (as in Firefox and IE), because it has lower ordinal value.

Comment: Spec says *"The two Strings are compared in an implementation-defined fashion."* Maybe this is the reason.